# Source for parable about two twins in the womb

Tags: death, pregnancy-birth, olam-haba-world-to-come, story-identification, ramchal

I once heard/read a parable about two babies in their mother's womb. It goes something like this.

> Two twins in the womb are speaking of the world to come, one believes it exists, the
> other not. Suddenly a hole appears with light, one of the babies is
> sucked outside, the other hears agitation, shouting, cries and thinks "I was right, it is
> over".
>
> For the baby that came out, a new world opens up. Whatever
> "worked" in the womb is suddenly completely different: he breathes
> differently, eats differently, moves differently but of course the "new world" is much
> more interesting.

This is of course a parable for the world to come, which will be much more interesting while being completely different.

**Does anyone know the source of this parable?** I thought it was from the Rambam or Ramban but never found it. The Gesher HaChaim (vol. 3, p. 28 in the [English translation](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0940118254/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_NX1B6D2T0HA49QCQTTF9)) mentions it without source. Someone else suggested it might be from the Ramchal.

Comment: There's also a song from the band Journeys about this (I would guess Conversation In The Womb from Volume 1).

Comment: Dr Wayne Dyer in his book "your sacred self" also has a similar parable. You can read it here ,click on "look inside" and you will see the parable https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0015KGWZQ?ref=aw_sitb_digital-text

Comment: What makes you think the Gesher HaChaim didn't come up with it himself?

Comment: @robev it is possible. I just think I saw it elsewhere in the name of a rishon. And someone I respect highly told me it was the Ramchal. I thought it was worth investigating and the *talmidei chachamin* from MY are often good at this

Comment: It is a surprising parable. When we speak about tweens and future world. Immediately Yaaqov and esav come in mind

Comment: I'm fairly certain Rav Tucachinsky created it himself...

Comment: Thought I heard it as being in the Chovos HaLevavos?

Answer (score 2):

Years later, I found a somewhat similar story quoted in R Akiva Tatz's [Anatomy of a search](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0899065503).

After checking with him, he pointed to [More Nevuchim 2:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_2.17.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as his source. It is not exactly the story in the question but close enough to have formed the basis for a "modernization" of the *mashal*.